# express.js + PATCH verb

Tags: express

Does Express support the HTTP verb "PATCH", as in:

```
app.patch("/api/resource", function(req, res){ ... });
```

I checked the docs and it seems pretty unclear to me.  They discuss GET and POST, but seem to lump everything else under "all the other HTTP verbs".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes.

Express.js has a dependency on [node-methods](https://www.npmjs.org/package/methods). The list of supported methods is found [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-methods/blob/master/index.js). The loop that creates the `app.VERB` methods for express is [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/8ba3f39b33042f59d50ef5b5fb87109d3f3a2a26/lib/router/route.js#L133).

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Express supports not only HTTP verb "patch", but all 23 HTTP verbs. The documentation keeps entries for the most used ones. See this link.

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.METHOD