# how to pass a node.js array variable to jquery for displaying those value in html table?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have an array variable in my node.js file.I am trying to display the values of this array in a tabular form on my html front end page.So how can I send this array variable to jquery/javascript so that I can append like this  $('body').html(string).

out.txt

```
IMAGE                  STATUS        NAMES
k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1   Up 2 days     k8s_POD   Deploy  Decomission Properties
eb516548c180           Up 2 days     k8s_cor   Deploy  Decomission Properties
```

index.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('out.txt', function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var array = data.toString().split(/\s+/);
    for(i in array) {
        console.log(array[i]);
    }
});
```

trying to do something very similar to the below mentioned code but with the node.js array variable present in the index.js file.

```
var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
  $.each(data, function(index, value){
         html += '<tr>';
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){
            html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
        });
        html += '<tr>';
     });
     html += '</table>';
     $('body').html(html);
```

How can I modify my code accordingly to send the array variable from index.js to frontend javascript or jquery.I think I have to use ajax for this.And once the variable is sent how will I $('body').html or append it to my html page in tabular fashion.Kindly Help.

Comment: I presume you have a node server that loads your client that contains the jquery snippet that you are showing. Perform a HTTP call from your client app that will hit an endpoint on your server that will contain data that you want. Changes should be done both on client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an array of strings in the success callback you are trying to iterate on the `value` but it is an string not another array.
You did not specified the content of out.txt so I assumed it was somehting like:

out.txt

```
test1 test2 test3 test4
```

I included the code for reading the file on a very simple server:
Calling `http://localhost:3000/` will result on `['test1','test2','test3','test4']`

server.js

```
const http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
  fs.readFile('out.txt', function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var array = data.toString().split(/\s+/);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(array));
    });

});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I changed the HTTP GET success callback because you have an array of strings so the content of `value` is the string itself not another array of strings, no inner `foreach` is required.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("http://localhost:3000", function(data, status){
    var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
           html += '<tr>';
           html += '<td>'+value+'</td>';
           html += '</tr>';     
        });
     html += '</table>';

     $("#content").append(html);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"> </div>
    <button>GET Data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Serving the html file on the server.

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
   //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

app.get('/out', function(req,res){
    fs.readFile('out.txt', function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        var array = data.toString().split(/\s+/);
    res.type('json')
        res.end(JSON.stringify(array));
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running at Port 3000");
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("/out", function(data, status){
        var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>'+value+'</td>';
            html += '</tr>';     
        });
        html += '</table>';
        $("#content").append(html);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

With the new provided out.txt

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
   //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

app.get('/out', function(req,res){
    fs.readFile('out.txt', function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;

        const array = [];
        var lines = data.toString().split('\n').filter((column) => column.length != 0);

        for(i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
             array.push(lines[i].split('  ').filter((column) => column.length != 0))        
    }
    const response = {headers:array[0], rows:array.slice(1, array.length)}; 
        res.type('json')
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running at Port 3000");
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("/out", function(data, status){
        var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
    html += '<tr>'; 
    $.each(data.headers, function(index, value){            
            html += '<th>'+ value+'</th>';     
        });
    html += '</tr>';
        $.each(data.rows, function(index, line){
            html += '<tr>';
        $.each(line, function(index, value){        
                html += '<td>'+ value+'</td>';
            })
            html += '</tr>';     
        });
        html += '</table>';
        $("#content").append(html);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Using the output of docker ps instead of an output file.

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
   //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

app.get('/out', function(req,res){
const {execSync} = require('child_process');
let output = execSync("docker ps -a --format 'table {{.Names}}\\t{{.Status}}\\t{{.Image}}'", { encoding: 'utf8'});

     const array = [];
     var lines = output.toString().split('\n').filter((column) => column.length != 0);

     for(i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
         array.push(lines[i].split('  ').filter((column) => column.length != 0))        
     }   
     const response = {headers:array[0], rows:array.slice(1, array.length)};    
     res.type('json')
     res.end(JSON.stringify(response));      
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running at Port 3000");
```

Comment: how do i run the html file?

Comment: i ran node server.js and i just yelds the json ["test1","test2","test3","test4",""] as output

Comment: how can i display this in tabular form?

Comment: and is express required for this in node.js?

Comment: No express is not required but it can help a lot. Take a look at this: https://medium.com/sharenowtech/there-are-expressjs-alternatives-590d14c58c1c

I will modify my answer serving the html

Comment: HI, the updated code works fine but the contents of my out.txt is the redirected output of the docker ps -a command

Comment: I have updated my question with the contents of the out.txt file.So in that case an array is impossible to use right ? the file contains totally 3 columns and i want it in the exact form but using html tables

Comment: okay its working now.What changes do i have to do if i want to pipe the output of the command "sudo docker ps -a  --format \"table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Image}}\"" to out.txt file before reading from it?

Comment: i tried using  process.exec("sudo docker ps -a  --format \"table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Image}}\"", function(err, stdout, stderr) {

Comment: but i keep getting err connection refused...is it beacuse i added it inside app.get('/out', function(req,res){  ?

Comment: thank you its working as desired.I just have one final request from you.I was asked to make new changes to the html page

Comment: I need 3 buttons namely  Deploy, Decomission and Properties in each of the rows of the html table..I have updated my out.txt in the question for this

Comment: when the decomission button is clicked it should run the command "docker stop <NAME>"  .Here NAME is the name of the container (corresponding to the container for which the button was clicked.

Comment: similary should run "docker start" for the deploy button!!

Comment: properties button is for changing the port of the image/container

Comment: Hi, to to this you create 3 endpoints on the node server you can use PATCH method, when you click the decommission button you do a ajax PATCH request for the server passing the image id you have and execute the command with ```execSync```.  This problem is a different question. Could you please accept this answer and ask another question with this?
Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271348/express-js-patch-verb and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13439828/4325878 helps

Comment: are you familiar with docker/Kubernetes containers?

Comment: any idea on how to change the port of the container using the properties button?

Comment: i heard that the only way to change the port is to stop the container and add the -p X:Y

Comment: But kubernetes does not allow stopping the container.I can only delete the pod completely.

Comment: I'm only familiar with Docker. 
To do port forward you need to stop it, sorry.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335444/how-do-i-assign-a-port-mapping-to-an-existing-docker-container