# Which HTTP verb should I use for removing a MongoDB sub-document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, http

Which HTTP verb should I use for removing a MongoDB sub-document?
Here's an example of my data:

```
test: 'some value',
rooms: [
    {
        id: '1'
        colour: 'brown'
    },
    {
        id: '2'
        colour: 'red'
    },
    {
        id: '3'
        colour: 'green'
    }
]
```

Let's say that I'm wanting to perform actions on a room in the rooms array.
If I wanted to change the colour of the room with id: '2', I would use the PUT verb:

```
app.put("/room", async (req, res) => {})
```

But what if I wanted to remove a room from the rooms array? Would I use PUT, since rooms is being updated, or would I use DELETE, because I'm deleting a room?

```
app.delete("/room", async (req, res) => {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which HTTP verb should I use for removing a MongoDB sub-document?

First hint: HTTP [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) doesn't define semantics for a payload - a delete request means to delete the mapping of the target uri to its representation.  All of it - there are no degrees of freedom that support "partial DELETE" semantics, in exactly the same way that there are no degrees of freedom that support "partial PUT" semantics.

---

Longer answer: part of the point of REST is that message semantics are uniform -- all resources understand requests the *same* way.

In particular, that means that your REST API sitting on top of MongoDB should work just like a WordPress site sitting on top of MySQL or a static web site sitting on top of the file system.

Expressed another way, the semantics of the messages don't vary with your implementation.  (For more on this idea, see [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)).

DELETE is analogous to removing a file system path - the contents of the file might still exist afterwards, but they will not be reachable using this same path.

And that's where I argue that DELETE breaks down for your context; you aren't deleting the resource (document), you are just changing its representation.  Therefore, you should be using one of the "change the representation methods" (PUT/PATCH/POST).

---

> Would I use PUT, since rooms is being updated

Maybe.  If the payload of the request is a complete representation of the document with changes made in line, then PUT make sense.  On the other hand, if the payload is a special "change room 2" message, then you should probably be using POST (see [Fielding, 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)).

Remember the uniform interface?  PUT is what you use when you are trying to save a new version of a static web page.  `GET /foo.html`, remove a paragraph that you don't want any more, then `PUT /foo.html` to deliver a copy of your document to the server, asking the server to modify its copy to match.

Similarly, think about how we submit questions and answers here on stack overflow.  We could, in theory, fetch the question as HTML, insert some new elements into the answer section, then PUT the edited version of the document back to the server.  But in practice, we fill out forms, and propose that the server integrate our form submission into the HTML.  Therefore, in this latter case, we use PUT rather than POST.

([PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) is similar to PUT, in that we are sending an edited representation to the server -- the difference being that with PATCH we are sending a patch document that describes the changes we have made to the document, rather than sending the entire document again.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Since my payload doesn't contain a complete representation of the document, I will use PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds more like a `PATCH` verb in the `REST` universe.

Also you are probably want to use `rooms/id` as an endpoint, but that's more of a personal take.

more about `PATCH` method:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789

```
... new HTTP/1.1 [RFC2616] method, PATCH,
which is used to apply partial modifications to a resource...
```

related SO question: [express.js + PATCH verb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271348/express-js-patch-verb/25271914)

with additional info about express and `PATCH` method.

Answer (score -1):

This is a question on how you want your program to function, and as long as you're consistent throughout none of your alternatives are wrong.

Personally I would reserve `DELETE` for operations that completely remove an entire entity from a database row, in your case that would be to completely delete the rooms array. If you delete something that has a database row ID and not only internal array id's, you would use `DELETE` for that.

I would use `PUT` or `PATCH` to update an existing array, `DELETE` to remove the database row (or 'document' in MongoDB) it's saved under.